# Why Can't I getX for this Point?

Tags: python, graphics

```
    def drawAllStars(window,numOfStars):
    starlist=list()
    for x in range(numOfStars):
        cntrx = random.randrange(1000)
        cntry= random.randrange(1000)
        cntr = graphics.Point(cntrx, cntry)
        drawstars(cntrx, cntry, 5, "black", window)
        starlist.append(cntr)
    print(starlist)
    return starlist

def getDistance(point1,point2):
    a= point1.getX()
    b= point2.getX()
    c= point1.getY()
    d= point2.getY()
    distance=  math.sqrt((b-a)**2 + ((d-c)**2))
    return distance

def balloonStarCollide(balloon, star):
    point1 = balloon.getCenter()
    point2= star
    distance= getDistance(point1, point2)
    if distance <= 30:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def checkForStarCollision(balloon, stars):
    for star in stars:
       collide = balloonStarCollide(balloon, stars)
       if collide == True:
           return True
```

So I've draw a list of stars and made a list of their centerpoints. Then I've got a function that gets the difference between the center of a given star and then compares it to that of a user controlled circle. The program breaks in the getDistance function, claiming that getX is not possible for a 'list' object.

Comment: Guessing `collide = balloonStarCollide(balloon, stars)` should be `collide = balloonStarCollide(ballon, star)`

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Wow. I'm ashamed of myself. If you want to make that an answer so I can rep you, feel free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `checkForStarCollision`. The line

```
collide = balloonStarCollide(balloon, stars)
```

should be

```
collide = balloonStarCollide(ballon, star)
```

Assuming `stars` is a list, that would explain your error message.